# Get date value with jinput

Tags: php, ajax, rsform

In my form I have selecting date with [datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) which i'm using only date picker.

I need to get the selected date value to do some calculation in php through ajax.
Here is my code but the result shows date starting 01/01/1970 !!

```
 public function getmydateHTML() {
     $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);         
     $dt = $jinput->get ('dvalue');         
     $date = $jinput->get ('selectedate');
     $sdt = strtotime($date);
     $newdate = strtotime("+$dt day", $sdt);
     echo   date('d/m/Y', $newdate);      
    exit;  
}
```

How can I get correct selected date value?

Comment: you need to look at the format that your datetimepicker is submitting to your script. The default is probably yyyy-mm-dd. Be sure your script is allowing for the date format being returned or else your strtotime is going to return an improper value.

Comment: @allogos It would be best if you included exactly what values you are receiving for `$dt` and `$date` only then can we work forward and help resolve this old question.  Remember, even if this is no longer an issue for you, this site intends to help future researchers -- please help to progress this page to a resolution.

Comment: @allogos please provide the necessary details to progress this abandoned page to a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it to:

```
"+$dt days"
```

Also, I may be wrong but, I believe you must provide dates in correct order as if dates diff is <0 then it would return 0 which corresponds to 01/01/1970